# webview отображает пустое пространство,вместо изображения

Tags: java, android, kotlin, изображения, webview

Всех приветствую. У меня возникла проблема. По крайней мере у меня,хотя может и у других тоже,webview не загружает изображение,т.е текст нормально загружается,а вот изображения нет. В моём коде я напрямую вставляю html код из json,а не загружаю его с сайта,чтобы упростить тестовый пример до минимума,но почему-то возникает проблема с загрузкой изображения,т.е вроде оно не появляется в webview (по крайней мере на android 13 (api 33)). Просто я делаю тестовый пример для демонстрации гуглу другого бага о котором,кстати,написано в readme. Подскажите пожалуйста,почему webview не отображает изображение,хотя при клике на него происходит его загрузка. Мой код находится на https://github.com/AlexandrKozlovskiy/test/tree/webviewIssue/. json,откуда я вставлял код,находится на https://xn----jtbhavgci6f.xn--p1ai/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/15438?_fields=content (поле content/rendered). Заранее благодарю всех за помощь.

Comment: Посоветуйте переводчик с языка тишины,т.к тот переводчик,который есть у меня,предлагает мне несколько вариантов.

Comment: вы включали javascript в webview?